# Auto Generate Objects in DBIx::Class ORM in Perl

Tags: perl, object, dbix-class

I started learning DBIx::class and I reach the point where you have to create the Objects that represents tables. Should this classes be created manually ( hard coding all the fields and relationships.....) or there is a way to generate them automatically using the database schema. I read something about loaders, but i did not know where they are really used.

Answer (score 2):

Odd that this question was never answered. Anyways I think what the poster is looking for is [DBIx::Class::Schema::Loader](http://search.cpan.org/~rkitover/DBIx-Class-Schema-Loader-0.06001/lib/DBIx/Class/Schema/Loader.pm)